# Enable HTTPS with CNAME Apache

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, ssl, apache-2.4, failover

I have two apache servers, both of which hostnames are primary.domain.com and secondary.domain.com

The Primary server will rsync and mirror all files to Secondary server as a backup. I am trying to make Secondary like a failover. I am trying to setup some CDN to pull through these servers by cdn subdomain, so I would be using cdn.domain.com to point to primary.domain.com

However if Primary server fails and I would quickly want to change cdn to point to Secondary, but all these are done with HTTPS. I have SSL installed on Primary and Secondary servers already, but HTTPS CNAME doesn't work.

How do I make it work? I tried changing ServerAlias with cdn already but it doesn't work, how do I make it so that the redirection can have HTTPS? Or is it not possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have some problems here:
a) Content distribution. If the interval between updates is not a problem, you can use rsync. In other case you must use something like [DRBD](http://drbd.linbit.com/) (master-slave) or distributed file-systems ([Ceph](http://ceph.com/) or [GlusterFS](https://www.gluster.org/)). If your web sites are using databases, you must choose some distributed database. 
b) Load balancing. You can use multiple DNS records. 
c) High availability. Some cluster solution, like [Linux-HA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux-HA).

There is many aspects related to the server, if they are distributed geographically or not, if you have two or more datacenters and the link speed...