# Direct A Record to alternate IP if primary does not resolve?

Tags: networking, a-record

Is it possible to configure an A record to point to multiple addresses?

For example:
website.abcd.com -> 1.1.1.1
website.abcd.com -> 2.2.2.2

So that if 1.1.1.1 is down, it will direct traffic to 2.2.2.2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can have an A record that points to more then 1 IP, or more accurately you can create multiple A records with the same name that each point to a different IP.

For example

```
website.example.com > 192.168.0.1
website.example.com > 192.168.0.2
website.example.com > 192.168.0.3
```

However the DNS server does not test to find out if the services on these IPs are available. So the DNS server will still give out an IP even if the website at the other end is down. This is "normally" done in a [Round Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) process.

The solution to this is something like [Amazon Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) (other services are available) With this you can configure a health check to work along side the DNS service. It will validate the health of the service by checking a web response for example. If the service is down it will not hand out the IP*

*There are many options, including weighting, geo-location etc.

Comment: How does the DNS determine which of the three to hand out? or will it only hand out the first one and ignore the other two?

Comment: @JaredTritsch See update and link

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is possible. But the traffic is not redirected automatically if one of them fails. In the mail case, you must use the MX record. The MX record is a type of record that specifies a mail server responsible for accepting email messages on behalf of a recipient's domain, and a preference value used to prioritize mail delivery if multiple mail servers are available.

> ```
> $TTL 2d ; zone default = 2 days or 172800 seconds $ORIGIN example.com.
> ; SOA using @ substitution @              IN       SOA
> ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
>                2016030400 ; serial number
>                3h         ; refresh =  3 hours
>                15M        ; update retry = 15 minutes
>                3W12h      ; expiry = 3 weeks + 12 hours
>                2h20M      ; nxttl = 2 hours + 20 minutes
>                ) ...
>                IN     MX     10  mail.example.com.
>                IN     MX     20  mail2.example.com.
>  mail          IN      A      192.168.0.3
>  mail2         IN      A      192.168.0.3
> ```

Preference number can have any value between 0 to 65535. You can use any value, but by convention, the values are multiples of 10. like 10 for higher priority, then 20 for lower, and 30 for further lower priority, and so on.

Comment: Edited question. these are web servers, not mail servers. My bad.

Comment: 5 minutes ago, I respond to [similar question](http://serverfault.com/a/761629/278323). Check if it's OK.